# To give color for option items in for loop

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

On my ajax success, I have 4 values `value.BookableResourceId,value.Name,value.FontColor,value.BackgroundColor`. My requirement is to add FontColor and BackgroundColor while creating the option with name and BookableResourceId to show items with its corresponding font & background colors.

```
$(resourceElement).select2({
    data: resourceData,
    closeOnSelect: true,
    placeholder: '(Empty)',
    allowClear: true,
}).on('select2:open', function (e) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/XX/YYY',
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                  for (var data in response) {                    
                      var newOption = new Option(response[data].Name, response[data].BookableResourceId, false, false);                                          
                      $(resourceElement).append(newOption).trigger('change');  
                  }
```

Below shows ajax response:

[image]

I have tried below code. But it fails data population also.

```
var add_Helpresrs = [];
$.each(response, function (index, value) {
                        add_Helpresrs.push(
                            {
                                id: value.BookableResourceId,
                                text: value.Name,
                                color: value.FontColor,
                                background: value.BackgroundColor
                            });
                    });

var newArray = [];
add_Helpresrs.map(function (item) {
                        newArray.push({
                            id: item.id,
                            text: '<span style="color:' + item.color + '; background:' + item.background + '">' + item.text + '</span>'
                        })
                    })
$(resourceElement).append(newArray).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Is something not working?

Comment: Data is populating fine in the Dropdownlist. Now I need to provide each item with its corresponding fontColor & backgroungColor receiving on the ajax success.

Comment: How are those colors being returned?  Are they names/hex values/RGB?  If there's only a specific set of colors you could use CSS classes.  If not you could append a style to the new Option for each value.

Comment: It returns all types based on the condition from server side

Answer (score 0):

Just add the color and background-color to the new option from the response:

```js
const response = [{
  Name: 'bob',
  BookableResourceId: 'bob\'s book',
  FontColor: 'red',
  BackgroundColor: 'blue'
}, {
  Name: 'Steve',
  BookableResourceId: 'steve\'s book',
  FontColor: 'green',
  BackgroundColor: 'orange'
}];

const select = document.querySelector('select');

response.forEach(book => {
  var newOption = new Option(book.Name, book.BookableResourceId, false, false);

  newOption.style.color = book.FontColor;
  newOption.style.backgroundColor = book.BackgroundColor;

  select.appendChild(newOption);
});
```

```html
<select>
  <option>-----</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Tried with same data mentioned above. Data is populated. But no color.